# jQuery onLoad issue

Tags: jquery, domdocument, onload

Can you explain me why **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/CZXqz/)** this snippet works and **[here](http://gioiellidisapone.it/test.html)** doesn't?

```
$('#about, #subscribe, #contact').hide();

$('.home').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
    if ($('.current').length === 0) {
        showContent($content)
    }
    else {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function() {
            showContent($content)
        });
    }
});

function showContent(content) {
    content.fadeIn(600);
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    content.addClass('current');
}
```

I put exactly the same code present in the fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

This means your code will only be run once the DOM has been initialised. Right now your code will run before the DOM is ready to be manipulated which will lead to the issues your experiencing.

In fiddles the code is automatically run on load (see the box which says `onLoad` in the fiddle you linked to).

Read about it in more detail here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not wrapping the code in `$(window).load({});` like you've specified in the fiddle.

```
  $(window).load(function() {
      $('#about, #subscribe, #contact').hide();

      $('.home').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
        var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
        if ($('.current').length === 0) {
            showContent($content)
        }
        else {
            $('.current').fadeOut(600, function() {
                showContent($content)
            });
        }
    });

    function showContent(content) {
        content.fadeIn(600);
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        content.addClass('current');
    } 
  });
```